# Facebook like button appears on top of fixed position element

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook-like

I have a mobile web page with a text box at the top and a little introduction followed by a twitter follow button and a Facebook like button. The problem I have is that I also have a menu button above this and when you click it a fixed position menu appears on top using jQuery. Unfortunately the like button still appears on top of the menu whilst the twitter button is behind it. If you'd like to see what I'm talking about visit go2gig.com on your iPhone and click the menu button. 
There are lots of different parts of code that contribute to this so it's a lot easier for me to show you the website than post the code however if you would rather I posted it do let me know and I shall.

Comment: This question is too localized as it stands, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting questions

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a z-index value for both (menu and fb button) ?

If no, try to set the biggest value to menu, as 1000 for example.

Than to FB-button, 999.

And tell me if solve it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I set a z-index of the menu to 100 and no change. I'll play around with it to see if it works but I think the fact that the facbook like button inserts an iframe with a bunch of stuff in it using javascript is making things awkward

Comment: Problem solved! I needed to add the z-index to both the menu container and the menu items. Also 1000 worked whereas before I was doing 100

Comment: Yeah, when I tried on my device, I realized that could be z-index problem. 

Any other problems?